# Override System Property in Java (without code)

Tags: java, windows-7, timezone

Is it possible to override system property (timezone etc.) in Java using predefined properties file for all Java applications?

I couldn't find such a file in my Windows 7 64bit OS.

Java version is 1.7.0_03 (JDK 64 bit)

Java "-Duser.timezone parameter cannot be used because it is a compiled exe file (does not accept java parameter). And we use those java applications as end users. We have not developed them. So setting timezone by programming is not an option.

Java uses different timezone other than systems'. I think there are some bugs with Java with Windows 7.

http://oraclesoon.blogspot.com/2010/04/windows-7-and-java-jdk-16-timezone.html

Comment: Have you found out what tool the exe was generated with? The answer might depend on that.

Comment: I havent't found which tool generated. But _JAVA_OPTIONS worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The _JAVA_OPTIONS envionment variable allows you to set commandline flags when java is run.

The following propagated into java for me (on OSX):
`export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Duser.timezone=Europe/Copenhagen'`

It is hard to know if it will work with your .exe setup also but give it a try.

You may need to restart after changing environment variables on windows.